# tensorflow - add tensor by name

Tags: tensorflow

Say I define a variable in a scope such as:

```
with tf.variable_scope("foo_1"):
    var1 = tf.Variable(...,name="var1")
```

and I want to reference it later to perform an operation (eg addition) with another variable something like;

```
varN = tf.Variable(...) + tf.get_variable(name="foo_1/var1")
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can remove the 
`name=`
part.

More details can be found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/sharing_variables#get_variable